# fetch record id for current call/meeting before saving to database while editing

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am dealing with alerting whether call/meeting slot is available or not before a user saves a call/meeting. My task mainly deals with the editing part. There are two approaches to edit a specific call.

1. Select a particular lead in leads page -> go to detail view -> Log Call -> save -> come back to same lead detail view again -> click on edit call in the activities subpanel. Now if you check the URL, you see a url parameter with name "`record=abcde-fghi...`" which I am using during validations.
2. Now go to activities menu on the top and in the calendar you see all the held calls. Click on a particular call and then edit it. Now in the edit page, when you check the URL, you don't see "`record=abcde-fghi...`" url parameter which is useful for me to do validations. How to get the record id in this case?

When I checked the save function, it is accessing this id from $bean. But I don't know how to access this bean before saving the call to database.

I am taking the form parameters- `startdate`, `mins`, `hours`, `parent_id`, `user_asign_id` etc and triggering an ajax call based on the record id for first case above, But I am missing record id for second case to validate the call/meeting.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The id is only being generated after you save the record, of course. And that's why you don't see any id in the url above.
A workaround is to use a different ajax call, depending on whether you have the id or not. You could use '-1' as your id and check the server for this '-1' id.
Hope it helps